# asp.net excel to database excel and access database coloumn names must be same?

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, ms-access

```
string b = "xa";
if (sa.HasFile)//Kullanıcı fileupload ile bir dosya seçmiş ise işlemleri gerçekleştir.
{
    if (sa.PostedFile.ContentType == "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" || sa.PostedFile.ContentType == "application/vnd.ms-excel") //Sadece jpeg dosyalarını yüklenmesine izin veriyoruz.
    {
        if (sa.PostedFile.ContentLength < 1024000000) //Maksimum 1MB'lık dosyaların yüklenmesine izin veriyoruz.
        {
            string isim = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            //Benzersiz bir isim oluşturduk.İsimlendirme için farklı yöntemlerde kullanabilirsiniz.
            sa.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/") + /*Session["kurumkodu"].ToString()*/ b + ".xlsx");
            //Sunucuda ki resimler klasörünün içerisine seçilen resmi oluşturduğumuz benzersiz isim ile kaydediyoruz.
            Label1.Text = "Dosya yüklendi";

            //Detaylı bir bilgi mesajı verdik.  
            string a = "xa";
            string Access = Server.MapPath("/App_Data/yeni.mdb");
            string Excel = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/") + a/*Session["kurumkodu"].ToString()*/ + ".xlsx"; ;
            string connect = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + Excel + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;HDR=NO";

            using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connect))
            {
                using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        cmd.Connection = conn;
                        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [MS Access;Database=" + Access + "].[Tablo1]  SELECT * FROM [DATA$]";
                        if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                        {
                            conn.Open();                                 
                        }
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                        {
                            conn.Dispose();
                            conn.Close();
                        }
                        cmd.Dispose();
                        Response.Redirect("yonlendir.aspx");
                    }       
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                        {
                            conn.Dispose();
                            conn.Close();
                        }
```

My code above. I want to make intolerant from coloumn names excel to access system. This code has an error like this:

> Coloumn names doesnt match.

How can I do without coloumn names?

Comment: If you insert all the data, you can without columns name.

Comment: How can?How can ı change Insert code?

Comment: Your columns in table [Data] is it equal to [Tablo1]'s columns ?

Comment: Yes .But I want to try this.İf ı change a coloumn name ,this code will be succesfull

Comment: that means if your SQL is select * ,it would error. But if you select fieldsName, it would success? If true, i think is the order problem.

Answer (score 0):

"How can I do?without coloumn names" No way.
But you can get the column names very easily. Open a `DbDataReader` to the destination table with `where 1 = 0` condition and use `GetSchemaTable` for this reader. It will contain the required column names in order, you can join them with commas and add this expression after the tablename: `Insert into [...].[Tablename] (<<fieldlist>>) Select * From ...`;